Function is callable from Thirdweb Dashboard but not from the front end
I can call the function from the Thirdweb Dashboard and I get appropriate outputs but whenever I try calling it from the frontend I get a very weird error
Here is the function:

function userStakeInfo(
        address _user
    )
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory _stakedTokenIds, uint256 _availableRewards)
    {
        return (stakers[_user].stakedTokenIds, availableRewards(_user));
    }

Functions called internally:

function availableRewards(
        address _user
    ) internal view returns (uint256 _rewards) {
        Staker memory staker = stakers[_user];

        if (staker.stakedTokenIds.length == 0) {
            return staker.unclaimedRewards;
        }

        _rewards = staker.unclaimedRewards + calculateRewards(_user);
        _rewards = (_rewards * (100 + getMultiplier(msg.sender))) / 100;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Function used to calculate the rewards for a user.
     * @return _rewards - The rewards for the user.
     */
    function calculateRewards(
        address _staker
    ) internal view returns (uint256 _rewards) {
        Staker memory staker = stakers[_staker];
        return (((
            ((block.timestamp - staker.timeOfLastUpdate) *
                staker.stakedTokenIds.length)
        ) * (rewardsPerDay+getBonusMultiplier(_staker))) / SECONDS_IN_DAY);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Function used to update the rewards for a user.
     * @param _staker - The address of the user.
     */
    function updateRewards(address _staker) internal {
        Staker storage staker = stakers[_staker];

        staker.unclaimedRewards += calculateRewards(_staker);
        staker.timeOfLastUpdate = block.timestamp;
    }


function getMultiplier(address _account) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint _stakingMultiplier = 0;
        uint256 _totalTokensHeld = 0;
        uint256 _len = SM_Contracts.length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
            _totalTokensHeld = walletHoldsToken(
                _account,
                SM_Contracts[i],
                SM_TokenIds[i]
            );
            _stakingMultiplier += SM_Multipliers[i] * _totalTokensHeld;
        }
        if (maxMultiplier == true) {
            if (_stakingMultiplier > maxMultiplierCap) {
                _stakingMultiplier = maxMultiplierCap;
            }
        }
        return _stakingMultiplier;
    }


function walletHoldsToken(
        address _account,
        address _contract,
        uint256 _id
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        IERC1155 token1155 = IERC1155(_contract);
        return token1155.balanceOf(_account, _id);
    }


Been trying to debug for 2 days and I cannot reach anywhere, any help would be appreciated.
Chain: Sepolia tesnet
Libraries: Latest Thirdweb SDK
EDIT
I tried using ethers too to call the availableRewards() function it works if I have nothing staked but if I have something staked I get a revert and I don't understand the error message or what is its origin


you need to add more infos so someone could help, which version of which library are u using in the frontend. what is the error! which blockchain

Edited thanks for the tip.

I figured out what was the issue, I had a typo calling the getMultiplier() with a msg.sender as an argument in a view function.
